# Middle-portion regex

Tags: regex

I'm tying to write some regex matching a *start* and *end* of a string.

start:

> https://www.example.com.au/

end:

> -end

Example input/match:

`Input                                   IsMatch
https://www.example.com.au/hithere-end   Y
https://www.example.com.au/hi-there-end  Y
https://www.example.com.au/hithere-endx  N
https://www.example.com.au/end           N`

This is what i have so far:

```
^https?://(www\.)?example\.com\.au/[A-z](\-end)$
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Careful, `[A-z]` matches more than just letters (e. g. it also matches `[` and other characters between ASCII `Z` and `a`). Use `[A-Za-z]` or make the regex case-insensitive and use `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com\.au\/(.+)-end$
```

Changes from your pattern:

- `/` are escaped (with `\`, 3 times).
- The first group changed to a *non-capturing* one (`?:`).
- `[A-z]` matches a **single** capital letter. Changed to `(.+)`
  (a **capturing** group).
- Removed parentheses from the last group (you don't want to capture it), hence `\` is also not needed.

The "middle part" you want to capture is in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
^(https?://(www\.)?example\.com\.au/)[A-z]*(-end)$
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this C# code

---

Somestring.StartsWith("https://www.example.com.au/")

Somestring.EndsWith("-end")